# How to insert datetime in this - " 2016-01-01T19:33:15-05:00" format in MSSQL using Java?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, java-8

I have an column defined as datetime(2) and I have to create a new date in this format - **2016-01-01T19:33:15-05:00**

```
Entity: private Date transactionTime;

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
Date date = null;
try {
    date = formatter.parse(formatter.format(new Date()));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
obj.transactionTime(date);
```

It is getting inserted in SQL as like this - "**2021-08-26 14:19:09.0000000**" but I need insert this in the format mentioned above.

Comment: Neither `DATETIME` nor `DATETIME2` types have no time zone information.

Comment: Even if DATETIME had time zone information, you already lost that information when you used `Date`. And formatting and then parsing it again is also a useless roundtrip. At minimum you should use a SQL type that supports offsets, and use `java.time.OffsetDateTime` on the Java side.

Comment: You don't store date as strings, you store dates as date datatype and format it on demand. That being said, you can use DATETIMEOFFSET datatype in sql server and mist likely it'll accept the string literal as-is.

Answer (score 2):

There is only column type, `datetimeoffset` that can hold the timezone offset (e.g. `-05:00` as mentioned in your question) value. Check the [Data type mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-basic-data-types?view=sql-server-ver15#data-type-mappings) documentation to learn more about it.

So, if you want to store the timezone offset value, change the column type to `datetimeoffset`. After that, you will be able to insert the value which you have mentioned in the question.

You can use the following code to access the stored value:

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT foo FROM mytable WHERE ...");
while (rs.next()) {
   DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset = rs.getObject(1, DateTimeOffset.class));
   System.out.println(dateTimeOffset);
} 
rs.close();
st.close();
```

where `foo` the name of the column of type, `datetimeoffset`.